# SQL Server 08 Express Installed: But how to make a local database?

Tags: windows-7, localhost, sql-server-2008-express

I try to connect to 127.0.0.1 with Windows Authentication using Management Studio Express 2008 but it never connects says it can't find the server or something. I ran the SQL Server Express 2008 Installer and it said that it was already installed but I can't find any wizard or shortcut to start up anything that will allow me to actually start setting up a local database, what gives?

(Windows 7 x64)

Services were off, turned them on, still not connecting to (local) because of an error: Error 40 could not open a connection to sql server error: 2

NOTE: Turned of windows firewall, same error! everything is local... services running, firewall down, tcp/ip enabled in config... hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, SQL Server Express will install into a "named instance" called **SQLExpress**.

Try connecting to:

- (local)\SQLExpress
- .\SQLExpress

`(local)` as well as just a dot `"."` stand for the local machine, and \SQLExpress is the default named instance name for SQL Server Express installations.

Comment: <hehe> glad I could help - been there, been burned myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration tool that should have been installed with Studio Express.  If you use that you should be able to find the settings for Remote Connections.  It may be that you have TCP/IP connections turned off (I can't remember what the default is) and only named pipes are available.  If that's the case you can either turn on TCP/IP or try connecting using your machine name in Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have your firewalls allowing access then connect to (local)  including parenthesis